# cannot use python to send post request with parameters and headers

Tags: python-3.x, post, request

I am trying to use python to send a post request, here is my code:

```
import requests
data = {
  'api_key': xxxxx,
  'api_id': xxxxx,
  'parameter1': 12
}
requests.post(url=API_ENDPOINT, data=data)
```

`api_key` and `api_id` are the headers and `parameter1` is the pass-in parameter. after I run the code, no error message is given, but the post request didn't work successfully. can you please help me to figure it out? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try sending the data as json

```py
import requests

api_key = "My_API_Key_Here"
api_id = "My_API_ID_Here"

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'api_key': api_key,
    'api_id': api_id
}
data = {
  'parameter1': 12
}

response = requests.post(API_ENDPOINT, json=data, headers=headers)

# Check the response
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Request was successful')
    print(response.json())  # If the response is in JSON format
else:
    print('Request failed with status code:', response.status_code)
    print(response.text)  # Print the response content for debugging
```

Comment: thanks! it worked! but I found that api_key and api_id should be put in the headers rather than data as they belong to headers. Would you please update your answer? Really thanks!

Comment: @RA.IBOY you're welcome, added the header, done.